# Retraining the model every time the new sample data is available (ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs))

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to retrain an existing machine learning model with new data and avoid retraining all historical data. Here is my code:

```
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN, TimeDistributed
model=Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(hidden_units, input_shape=input_shape, activation=activation[0]))
model.add(Dense(units=dense_units, activation=activation[1]))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(inputs1, outputs1, epochs = 500, batch_size = 32)

model.save('my_model.h5')

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
#Retraining
model.fit(inputs2, outputs2, epochs = 500, batch_size = 32)
```

My problem is that when the length of the new data and the length of the old data are not equal, I have this error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). This could be due to issues in input pipeline that resulted in an empty dataset. Otherwise, please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

I want to fit the model every time the new sample data is available.